Ubuntu 24.04 OSK Problem
I developed a wxWidgets V3.2.4 application that is running on Ubuntu 22.04 desktop with Ubuntu's build in onscreen keyboard turned on and my application works just fine.
I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 24.04 desktop, but now my wxWidgets V3.2.4 application does not work correctly with Ubuntu's onscreen keyboard.  Every time I press a button on my application to show another of my application's windows, the onscreen keyboard pops up.  This did not happen before moving to Ubuntu 24.04.  Why? Is there a way to program around this problem, or do I need to go back to Ubuntu 22.04 and wait until the problem is fixed?
Best regards,
WFG

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

you should consider this post from OMG Ubuntu when deciding your next steps.
